# Using JST templates with backbone-forms

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms, jst

I am trying out backbone-forms backbone plugin and want to use JST templates to make custom forms. Looks like it doesn't work with JST out of the box so has anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Which templating engine do you want to use?  Most are supported, underscore is used itself from within the plugin.

Comment: See https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#example-fully-customise-forms-and-templates for an example using underscore templates, but lots of others can be used in it's place.